# QTableView row setEnabled equivalent function call?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

What I'm looking for is the ability to "Grey out" a row in the table, I'm using a `QTableView` with the following flags set:

```
this->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
this->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
```

The `QTableView` is uneditable but basically as expected when a row is clicked it gets highlighted blue. I want to add a context menu option to grey out a row instead of hiding it. Basically with other widgets you can call `setEnabled(bool)` and it just makes it so you can see the widget but not click on it or change values etc. I'm wondering if there is an equivalent for a single row in a `QTableView` or am I going to have to do some awkward hackery in with stylesheets etc?

Comment: if you are using any QAbstractTableModel(or other), data(...) function can be usable for this purpose. Do you use?

Comment: Yea i am using QTableModel how does `data()` accomplish this?

Comment: QTableModel is not a standard Qt class. What exact class do you use as the model?

Comment: @PavelStrakhov sorry i Meant QAbstractTableModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using `QAbstractTableModel`.

```
def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            # myItems is your data list for QAbstractTableModel
            # myObject.isDisabled is your decision flag 
            if self.myItems[index.row()].isDisabled is True: 
                return QVariant(Qt.gray)
        # other roles if needed (Display, align, foreground, etc.)
```

to read full documentation -> [QtDoc.QAbstractTableModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstracttablemodel.html#details)

Comment: Cheers this is how i ended up using it in the end

Answer (score 1):

Whether a cell is enabled or not is controlled by the `Qt::ItemIsEnabled` flag returned by the `flags` method of `QAbstractItemModel`.

By default, this returns `Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable`. Just reimplement `flags()` in your model and leave out `Qt::ItemIsEnabled`:

```
Qt::ItemFlags YourModel::flags(const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    Qt::ItemFlags f = Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
    if (rowIsEnabled(index.row())
        f |= Qt::ItemIsEnabled;
    return f;
}
```

See the docs: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags

Comment: Thanks for the answer this does seem to work, iv implemented in my QAbstractTableModel class and its now disabling (graying out) rows on a click the only problem is that if a row is not enabled then i cant select it anymore even though the selectable flag is still set, i assume that not being enabled disables all functionality basically... i want to be able to select still so that i can right click a row to enable it again based on selected rows

Comment: @AngryDuck Then you don't actually want to disable the row, but just highlight it differently. Use a background color as others have suggested.